# How can i use mCustomScrollbar instead of the default browser scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mcustomscrollbar

I used this code:

```
$("body").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "3d-thick-dark",
      scrollButtons: { enable: true }
});
```

mcustomscrollbar work on another elements. but doesn't work on body or html element!

Comment: *"does not work"* - please be more specific.  Any browser console errors?  Network tab errors?  Does something, but not a dark 3d scrollbar?  Do other options work? Did you include the 2x .js files?  Did you include the css?  Have a read of [mcve] - specifically "complete".

Comment: Which version of jquery / mcustomscrollbar are you using?

Comment: mcustomscrollbar work on another elements. just doesn't work on body or html element.

Comment: Thanks, My problem was solved.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22074687/2181514

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
I just had to use the following code in Css.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```